# C++ template parameters

Tags: c++

Ran into this blog post (mariusbancila.ro/blog/2021/03/15/typename-or-class) when discussing about typename vs. class. The post claimed the following program worked but I can't confirm that. Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct wrapper
{
    using value_type = T;
    value_type value;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct dual_wrapper
{
    using value_type1 = T;
    using value_type2 = U;
    value_type1 value;
    value_type2 another_value;
};

template <typename T>
struct foo
{
    T wrapped_value;
    typename T::value_type get_wrapped_value() { return wrapped_value.value; }
};

int main() {
    foo<wrapper<int>> f { {42} };  // works fine
    std::cout << f.get_wrapped_value() << '\n';
    foo<dual_wrapper<int,double>> f2{ {43, 15.0} }; /// <<<< HOW CAN THIS LINE WORK???
    std::cout << f2.get_wrapped_value() << '\n';
}
```

As you can see struct foo tried to apply both wrapper and dual_wrapper. The dual_wrapper didn't work in my experiment. Did I miss anything or how to make foo work with both wrapper and dual_wrapper?

Comment: What is `typename T::value_type` when `T` is `dual_wrapper`?  I presume whatever error you are getting is mentioning this.

Comment: Presumably, they meant to write `value_type` instead of `value_type1` in `dual_wrapper`. As it stands, the code doesn't compile. Blog writer probably forgot to proofread.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the confirmation: it can't work!

Comment: @SilvioMayolo that's the best guess why the blog post stated that way :-).

Comment: For me it can't work. Tested right now with c++20 enabled.

Maybe the author meant to write value_type instead of value_type1 in DualWrapper ? in this case it compiles

Comment: @CharlesG Not sure what the original intent was. Important thing is it doesn't work as it is. I thought I missed some new C++ features there so good to get confirmation here.

Comment: btw I don't see anything relate to typename vs. class here. (despite `typename T::value_type`, but why use a so convolved example?)

Comment: @appleapple you need to read the rest of the post in which there are cases class needs to be used. Here is just snippet of the post.

Comment: _"HOW CAN THIS LINE WORK???"_ In the instantiation of `foo`, the type `T` is `dual_wrapper<int,double>` and this specialization doesn't have member `value_type`, so you have invalid return type `dual_wrapper<int,double>::value_type`

Comment: On other hand if you replaced the return type with `auto` placeholder, the type would be in this case `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the blog article is different from yours:

```
auto get_wrapped_value() { return wrapped_value.value; }
```

You have:

```
typename T::value_type get_wrapped_value() { return wrapped_value.value; }
```

But `dual_wrapper` has no `value_type` member alias.

By using the `auto` return type, the type gets deduced from `wrapped_value.value` (which is `wrapper::value_type` for `foo<wrapper>` and `dual_wrapper::value_type1` for `foo<dual_wrapper>`).

Well on a second read I realized that the blogpost starts with the line you have but in the next section introduces `foo` with the `auto` return type ("As a parenthesis, there is another alternative solution to this particular problem from this example (given than we only need the wrapped value type for the return type of a function). That is the use of auto for the return type.")